# Using Jaro-Winkler similarity to recognize matching strings

Tags: algorithms, approximation, strings

How do I use the [Jaro-Winkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) similarity measure to test whether two strings should be considered to match each other?

I tried comparing the Jaro-Winkler score to a fixed threshold: e.g., if the similarity measure is greater than 0.9, consider the two strings to match.  However, this approach does not always work, as shorter strings will return a smaller similarity score.

I also tried the Levenshtein edit distance, but it wasn't adequate for my uses as it did not always guarantee a match.

Comment: 1. What does "did not guarantee a match" mean?  Can you give an example? 2. I don't think the question is answerable as it stands, because the answer will depend on the problem.  In particular, what's the distribution of string-pairs that should be considered to match, and distribution of non-matching pairs?  What's the probabilistic model here?  3. What do you mean by matching two datasets, or resolving them?  Are you just comparing two strings, or is it something more?

Comment: In short: define what it means for two strings to match.